# how to identify a child object by class-transformer ? | Nest.js

Tags: javascript, nestjs, class-transformer

I am trying to parse a json body to a JavaScript object with the library "class-transformer" but he doesn't recognize my child objects.

This is the json file:

```js
{
  "shops": [{
      "shopId": 1,
      "name": "La piscine Marius-Leclercq",
      "address": "99 Avenue Barbusse, 62440 Harnes",
      "description": "La piscine Marius-Leclercq est située en plein centre de la ville dans la rue Barbusse. Différentes spécialités sportives y sont proposées. Un bassin de 25 mètres de long vous accueille du lundi au dimanche ainsi qu’un petit bain pour les activités comme l’aquagym, l’aquadouce ou le jardin aquatique.",
      "email": "piscinemariusleclercq@contact.fr",
      "phone": "03 21 13 96 00",
      "localisation": {
        "lat": 50.450157165527344,
        "long": 2.898190498352051
      },
      "vidoLink": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqDEgCBYMxA&ab_channel=AvallonVision",
      "pictures": [{
          "idPicture": 1,
          "link": "https://zupimages.net/up/21/02/cpri.jpg"
        },
        {
          "idPicture": 2,
          "link": "https://zupimages.net/up/21/02/3mkk.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "openShop": [{
          "dayWeek": "Monday",
          "hourStart": "12:00:00",
          "endHour": "13:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Monday",
          "hourStart": "16:15:00",
          "endHour": "19:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Tuesday",
          "hourStart": "16:15:00",
          "endHour": "19:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Thursday",
          "hourStart": "10:00:00",
          "endHour": "13:30:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Thursday",
          "hourStart": "14:00:00",
          "endHour": "19:15:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Saturday",
          "hourStart": "10:00:00",
          "endHour": "12:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Saturday",
          "hourStart": "14:00:00",
          "endHour": "17:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Sunday",
          "hourStart": "8:00:00",
          "endHour": "12:00:00"
        }

      ]
    },
    {
      "shopId": 2,
      "name": "Climb up",
      "address": "Plaine sportive, 110 Rue Jean Jaurès, 59810 Lesquin",
      "description": "Depuis plus de 15 ans nous cultivons la diversité au sein de nos structures. Diversité de profils, de visions et de sensibilités. Nos nombreux échanges ont ainsi donné jour à un concept de salles d’escalade pensées comme des lieux de vie ouverts à tous.",
      "email": "climbup@contact.fr",
      "phone": "03 20 07 57 42",
      "localisation": {
        "lat": 50.5865602,
        "long": 3.1071495
      },
      "vidoLink": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-3a9GghAR0&ab_channel=ClimbUp",
      "pictures": [{
          "idPicture": 3,
          "link": "https://zupimages.net/up/21/02/z8st.jpg"
        },
        {
          "idPicture": 4,
          "link": "https://zupimages.net/up/21/02/6yh3.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "openShop": [{
          "dayWeek": "Monday",
          "hourStart": "8:00:00",
          "endHour": "23:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Tuesday",
          "hourStart": "8:00:00",
          "endHour": "23:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Wednesday",
          "hourStart": "8:00:00",
          "endHour": "23:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Thursday",
          "hourStart": "8:00:00",
          "endHour": "23:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Friday",
          "hourStart": "8:00:00",
          "endHour": "23:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Saturday",
          "hourStart": "10:00:00",
          "endHour": "23:00:00"
        },
        {
          "dayWeek": "Sunday",
          "hourStart": "8:00:00",
          "endHour": "12:00:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There are my DTOs:

```js
export class ShopEntity {
    shops : ShopDto[];
}
```

```js
export class ShopDto {
  @Expose({
    name: 'shopId'
  })
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  description: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  localisation: {
    lat: number;
    long: number;
  }
  videoLink: string;
  offers: OfferDto[];
  pictures: PictureDto[];
  openShop: OpenShopDto[];
}
```

And this my line of code:

```js
 let shopsTab = plainToClass(ShopEntity, body);
```

I succeeed in gettting my first object from ShopEntity but the tab shops is undefined.

Comment: what is 'body'? can you share the service& controller method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all of your child objects, you should add `@Type(() => ChildObjectType)`. Arrays do not serialize otherwise due to how generics get reflected in typescript. As a general rule, when I'm working with sub-objects in `class-transformer` I make sure to add the `@Type()` decorator.